# windbg shows different instruction at address when you set the breakpoints in 2 different breaks but not the same break (nvd3d9wrapx thunk in user32)

Tags: windows, windbg

In the first example I only set a breakpoint on `user32!CreateWindowExW`

[image]

In the second example, I set 2 breakpoints at the same time on  `user32!CreateWindowExW` and `notepad!WinMain`

[image]

In the 3rd example I place a breakpoint on `notepad!WinMain`, wait for it to break, and then I place the breakpoint on `user32!CreateWindowExW`, and this time it shows the jump instruction.

[image]

I confirmed that it does indeed jump to that address by stepping through, and I confirmed that the jump isn't there in the first 2 examples by unassembling as well as stepping to the next instruction. The callstack is identical in all 3 scenarios.

It reproduces every time. This is Windows 7 btw Windbg x64 10.0

What is going on ?

Comment: what's mapped at this `0x6fff00340` address? This looks like some hooking and `jmp` trampoline

Comment: @PawełŁukasik from !address: + 06fff0000 070000000 000010000 MEM_PRIVATE MEM_COMMIT PAGE_EXECUTE_READ <unknown> [dtrR............]. It's clearly some trampoline block allocated by the nvd3d9wrapx  because it then injects the jump instruction to the trampoline but I do not know why windbg is behaving like that

Comment: It's not a trampoline function exactly. What it jumps to is just a single rip-relative memory indirect jump to an address, the address is stored with it. This is an address of a procedure  loc_7FEFA2C3E40 in nvd3d9wrapx that I haven't got the symbols for